# Use PHP to split a sentence into shorter sentences

Tags: php, string

Is there a certain way I can apply to split a sentence into smaller sentences to perform a databas search. My client want to perform a database search like in this example:

First request: Claimant had an accident in the coffee shop
Second request: Claimant had an accident in the coffee `(in case document states it was a bar etc.)`
Third request: Claimant had an accident in the
...
Last request: Claimant

I find a lot of topics about splitting sentece by word, but nothing about chunks of words. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are many ways to skin this particular cat.

Comment: how should be defined the "rotating" mechanism for different requests in your task? I mean, how does the program know how many words should contain each request?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, each new request should be equal to previous request minus one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution with `explode`, `implode` and `array_slice` functions:

```
$str = "Claimant had an accident in the coffee shop";
$words = explode(" ", $str);
$count = count($words);

echo implode(" ", array_slice($words, 0, $count)) . "<br>"; // first request
while (--$count) {
    echo implode(" ", array_slice($words, 0, $count)) . "<br>";
}
```

The output:

```
Claimant had an accident in the coffee shop
Claimant had an accident in the coffee
Claimant had an accident in the
Claimant had an accident in
Claimant had an accident
Claimant had an
Claimant had
Claimant
```

Comment: You are the real MVP!

Comment: It's great to hear it! Thank you very much )

Answer (score 1):

You could use `explode(" ", $str)`. Then, you can reconstruct the sentence word by word (except for the words outside that particular iteration).

Something like this (the loops may be off, I've never written PHP before):

```
for ($x = count($sentence); $x >0; $x--) {
    for($y = 0; $y < $x; $y++) {
      echo $cars[$y];
       echo "<br>";
   }
   echo "<br>"
}
```

Comment: That is somehow correct if I use your approach in reverse.

Comment: @IvanVenediktov Feel free to use it however you want. You can also accept my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One more option using string functions:

```
$string = 'Claimant had an accident in the coffee shop';

echo "$string<br>";  // use the entire string first as first iteration of
                     // the loop will chop off the last word

while ($string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, ' '))) {
    echo "$string<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a regexp that splits based on punctuation marks.  This example, which splits on periods, question marks, exclamation marks and the end-of-line, should get you started:

```
$data = 'First request: Claimant lost $500 in the coffee shop.  Second request: (unknown) Claimant had an accident?  Third request: Claimaint went to the hospital!  End of report';

preg_match_all("/\s*(.*?(?:[\.\?\!]|$))/", $data, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $sentence) {
    if (preg_match("/\S/", $sentence) ) {
        print "Sentence: $sentence\n";
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Sentence: First request: Claimant lost $500 in the coffee shop.
Sentence: Second request: (unknown) Claimant had an accident?
Sentence: Third request: Claimaint went to the hospital!
Sentence: End of report
```